# How to combine element in array which has the same property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For the following array:

```
[{a:1,b:1},{a:5,b:2},{a:10,b:2},{a:20,b:3}]
```

How do I get a new array which combines the elements with the same value of property `b`, and sum the value of property `a`? In this case, I hope to get the following result:

```
[{a:1,b:1},{a:(5+10),b:2},{a:20,b:3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like this:

```js
const result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const prev = acc.find((item) => item.b === cur.b)

  if (prev) {
    prev.a += cur.a
  } else {
    acc.push(cur)
  }

  return acc
}, [])
```